# Why to occur this error?

Tags: jquery

Line 56, column 36: document type does not allow element "p" here

```
    controlsBefore: '<p id="controls">',
```

**I have used this code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

$(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#slider").easySlider({
        controlsBefore: '<p id="controls" >',
        controlsAfter:  '</p>',
        prevId: 'prevBtn',
        nextId: 'nextBtn'
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: that depends upon plugin

Comment: @Mr.Alien: if you look at easyslider plugin demo, there provided same code as here...

Comment: I don't see them making use of the controls before and after though..

Comment: I have tried but i can't to solve it, than any codings need to add this codings.

Comment: Look at the plugin's documentation/site.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/V9c2u/

Working fine on my end.

**JS:-**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#slider").easySlider({
        controlsBefore: '<p id="controls" >',
        controlsAfter: '</p>',
        prevId: 'prevBtn',
        nextId: 'nextBtn'
    });
});
```

Comment: @user2688776 - Does this answer your question?